# Union of two sigma algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let F and G be two σ-algebras of subsets of Ω.
Is  $F\cup G$, the collection of subsets of Ω lying in either F or G a
σ-algebra?

I am able to prove this using an example:-

Let F={$\varnothing$,$\Sigma$}

and G=$2^\Sigma$

So their union would be the bigger set G,which is a $\sigma$ algebra already.
based on this can I argue that whenever I am union-ing two $\sigma$ algebras , one will be the subset of the other and so the result would be the bigger set which is already a $\sigma$ algebra?

Comment: I think you swapped $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$ partway through . . .

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is incorrect. In fact, you haven't really provided *any* reasoning! How do you go from an *example* of one $\sigma$-algebra being contained in another, to the claim that for *every* pair of $\sigma$-algebras, one is contained in the other? There's no reason to believe that the example you give is somehow "the usual case."

HINT: For each element $a\in\Omega$, the set $\Sigma_a=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{a\}, \Omega\setminus\{a\}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (exercise). For $a, b\in\Omega$ with $a\not=b$, what can you say about $\Sigma_a$ versus $\Sigma_b$? Does either contain the other?

Thinking more about this example, do you see how to answer your main question?

Comment: I thought of it like this:-  Since every σ-algebra must contain Ω, so their union contains Ω. Now since $Ω^c$ is ∅ it must also be present(by  σ-algebra property) in the union. Now $Σ_a$ already has {a} and ${a}^c$,same for $Σ_b$. So their union will contain both. hence every property is fulfilled.

Comment: @SukantaChatterjee I think you need to re-examine the definition of $\sigma$-algebra. A collection of sets, $C$, is a $\sigma$-algebra iff it is closed under complement, countable unions, and countable intersections. Is the set $\Sigma_a\cup\Sigma_b$ *really* a $\sigma$-algebra? (HINT: can you find two elements $X, Y\in\Sigma_a\cup\Sigma_b$ such that $X\cup Y$ is **not** in $\Sigma_a\cup\Sigma_b$?)

Comment: Also, you still haven't addressed the question of whether either of $\Sigma_a, \Sigma_b$ is contained in the other. Do you see what the answer to this is?

Comment: No $Σ_a$ and $Σ_b$ are not contained in one another.So my previous assumption was wrong.Also X={a} and Y={b} then XUY ={a,b} $\notin$ $Σ_a∪Σ_b$. So it is not closed under union, hence not a σ-algebra.

Comment: @SukantaChatterjee That's exactly right. So you've shown that the union of two $\sigma$-algebras need not be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot.@Noah Schweber You actually walked me through the entire proof instead of giving one directly. This felt really good! :)

Comment: @SukantaChatterjee Glad to hear it!